blazor static server rendering localization
How to setup localization in Blazor 8 Static Server rendering.
I'm new to Blazor and want to make application in Blazor static server rendering but on the web is only code for interactive server or wasm.
This is must for my application.

Static rendering is the default so you just don't explicitly add any of the interactivity modes.

I want to avoid interactive mode, this will be app mostly used on mobile device and mobile device after short time is losing connection with server. Pages are mostly static, so I don't want to use interactivity. Also is so weird to lack any information about this topic.

For information about language localization and internationalization, Microsoft has a lot of resources on this. See: localization You are really making this confusing asking about static server side rendering. That's a rendering option. Other than not doing this interactively, it is irrelevant whether you do this in blazor server, blazor wasm, or any net core application.

We need to see your attempts and know more about what you are actually doing that isn't working - "how to setup localization" is probably too big a topic as it involves a lot of steps that are all documented in tutorials describing this process. See for example: globalization and localization in net core

Thank you, you pointed me in right direction..
